# Playframework i18 date binding

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

Am I missing something (again) or is there a (bad) lack of internationalization support for form binding in Play 2.0 (Java) ?

Our system should support at least english and portuguese, which use different patterns for dates (dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy).

On the other hand I only found one way to define a custom date format: using an annotation (play.data.format.Formats.DateTime) on the model class. Not a solution in our case since **the format depends on the user**.

Any date.format.[locale] parameter defined in the application.conf seems to be ignored, which is not surprising since the Formats.DateFormatter has only one pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i finally got this "thing" working. The solution might be useful for others. I'm still not 100% sure that i'm not misusing the framework...

(1) I wrote my own DateFormatter which uses a map Locale/SimpleDateFormat instead of a unique pattern (like base framework class).

Because of what seems to be (one more) [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497470/playframework-2-0-1dateformatter-receives-system-locale) in Play Java, my overrided parse(String date, Locale locale) ignores the locale parameter and uses the request to get the preferred language.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class DateFormatter extends Formatters.SimpleFormatter<Date> {

    private Map<Locale, SimpleDateFormat> formats;
    private SimpleDateFormat defaultFormat;

    public DateFormatter(String defaultPattern) {
        formats = new HashMap<Locale, SimpleDateFormat>();      
        defaultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(defaultPattern);
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(String date, Locale locale) throws ParseException {

        Logger.debug("Parsing date " + date + " for locale " + locale);

        Context ctx = Context.current();
        if (ctx != null) {
            Lang preferred = Lang.preferred(ctx.request().acceptLanguages());
            Locale loc = preferred.toLocale();
            return getFormat(loc).parse(date);
        } else {
        return getFormat(locale).parse(date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Date date, Locale locale) {
        return getFormat(locale).format(date);
    }

    public void addPattern(Locale locale, String pattern) {
        formats.put(locale, new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale));
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = formats.get(locale);
        if (format == null)
            return defaultFormat;
        else
            return format;
    }   

}
```

(2) This DateFormatter is configured and registered by the application global object at application load.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {

    registerDateFormatter(app);

}

/**
 * Registers a custom date formatter using configured
 * available languages and custom date formats.
 * 
 * Browses the locales defined in langs parameter and
 * for each one loads the date format defined in the
 * parameters custom.date.format.xx
 * 
 * Gets also the default (fallback) format defined in
 * date.format. If no one is defined uses an hard-coded
 * format yyyy-MM-dd
 */
private void registerDateFormatter(Application app) {

    Configuration config = app.configuration();

    // Get default format
    String defaultPattern = config.getString("date.format");
    if (defaultPattern == null)
        defaultPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter(defaultPattern);

    // Get date format from configuration
    for (Lang lang:    Lang.availables()) {
        Locale locale = lang.toLocale();
        String pattern = app.configuration().getString("custom.date.format." + lang.code());                        
        if (pattern != null)
            formatter.addPattern(locale, pattern);        
    }

    // Register the formatter for java.util.Date
    Formatters.register(Date.class, formatter);        
}
```

The configuration (in application.conf) is:

```
# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="pt-br, en"
#
date.format="MM/dd/yyyy"
custom.date.format.en = "MM/dd/yyyy"
custom.date.format.pt-br = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

(custom. is needed in parameter names, using directly date.format.xx throws an error)